# Apply customer specific price

Tags: custom, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have to make a shop on which products' prices are specific per customer.

I must call an external service which returns me a product price depending of a customer and an ordered quantity.

First, do you think it's possible ?

I don't know where to start. I think I need to programmatically apply a custom shopping cart price rules defined by a custom extension but I don't know how to do this.

Where to start ?
How/Where to deal with price value which depend of ordered quantity ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hello You need to override the Price Model name as `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price`

and override the Method `getPrice($product)` and hear you can call the external price price through API.

For Example. this `pseudo code`

```
if(you have customer Id then) {
        // Call the Extenal API and bind the Price hear.
        return Mage::helper('price/data')->getPrice($product);
    } else {
        //else return Default Magento Price.
        return $product->getData('price');
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I take control over the product price. Thank you.

But How/Where to deal with price value which depend of ordered quantity ?

Comment: I can not understand your question..

Comment: I have to apply a price based on the customer and, at the same time, the quantity.

Exemple : for the same product, customer BB has negotiated unit price of 50$ per 100 items and customer AA has negotiated  unit price of 30$ per 100 items (because he is a big customer or a fine negotiator for exemple).

When the customer change the quantity of item in the shopping cart, i should adapt the unit price of my product.

Hope I'm clear enough... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Magento offers you the "tier prices" to deal with this. When you go to the "edit product"-screen in the backend, you can find this feature under the "prices" tab.

I doubt that the price is really different per customer; probably, this complexity can be reduced to a few customer groups that share the same price level. With tier pricing, you can apply a separate price per customer group and per quantity ordered.

Your workflow would then be to import the prices on a regular basis from your external service and save them to the tier prices. I am in mobile atm, but can elaborate my answer later if this is what you want.